# If electron moved in a definite orbit, would that violate Heisenberg uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, orbital-motion, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, determinism

If hypothetically a electron does manage to move in a specified orbit (we always find it anywhere on a particular locus), would it break Heisenberg uncertainty principle?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574867, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192599

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does electron orbital theory contradict the Heisenberg uncertainty principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574867/)

Answer (score 0):

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle states that one can not define the position and the momentum of a particle simultaneously with an arbitrary precision.

Keep in mind that Bohr's model has a classical assumption: **electrons move in circular orbits under the influence of Coulomb force**. That being said, since Bohr's model assumes electrons to orbit around nucleus like planets do around stars where centrifugal force $F_{centrifugal}=\frac{m_e v^2}{r}$ is counterbalanced by the Coulomb's force $F_{coulomb}=\frac{k e^2}{r^2}$ ($Z=1$ for Hydrogen).

Here you can see that the position and velocity(momentum) of the electron has precise values which looks like a contradiction to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle but this is due to the classical assumption that was made in the very beginning.